# Difference between using structures with methods and with functions and classes?

Tags: c++

Recently I was seeing one github project written in C++ that define objects with `structs`.

Example:

```
struct Example
{
    std::string message;

    Example() 
    {
        message = "foo";
    }

    void setMessage(std::string newMsg)
    {
        message = newMsg;
    }

    void getMessage(std::string newMsg)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

In researches, I found a definition of the difference between define object with `struct` and `class`, is: in `struct`, methods, functions, and attributes are public by default, in `class` the same are private by default.

My questions are: What are the benefits to use structs than classes?